# haskell alex: parse error on import?

Tags: haskell

I've just took up haskell and alex/happy because I wanted to write a parser. However, I ran into this problem:

source: lexer.x

```
{
module ValkenLexer where

strip :: String -> String
strip s = take ((length s) - 2) (drop 1 s)
}

%wrapper "basic"

$digit = 0-9
$alpha = [a-zA-Z]

tokens :-
  $white+                           ;
  $alpha+                               { \s -> TokIdent s }
  \"[^\"]*\"                       { \s -> TokStr strip(s) }
  =                                     { \s -> TokSlash}
  \|                                    { \s -> TokPipe }
  \/                                    { \s -> TokSlash }
  \n                                    { \s -> TokEol}
  \%$alpha+                              { \s -> TokVar (drop 1 s)}

{

data Token = TokIdent String
           | TokStr String
           | TokEq
           | TokPipe
           | TokSlash
           | TokEol
           | TokVar String
             deriving (Eq,Show)

}
```

and got:

```
\->>> alex lexer.x && ghc lexer.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling ValkenLexer      ( lexer.hs, lexer.o )

lexer.hs:15:1: parse error on input `import'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It must have generated a file called `lexer.hs`, please post that file content

Comment: At a guess, knowing nothing about alex: probably it's generating some imports, but putting them after your `strip` definition; but imports must come first in Haskell files. Move your definition of `strip` to the footer instead.

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel Wagner predicted, function definitions need to go on the footer. You can only put the module declaration and import statements on the header. Additionally, you need to change `TokStr strip(s)` to `TokStr (strip s)`

```
{
module ValkenLexer where
}

%wrapper "basic"

$digit = 0-9
$alpha = [a-zA-Z]

tokens :-
  $white+                           ;
  $alpha+                               { \s -> TokIdent s }
  \"[^\"]*\"                       { \s -> TokStr (strip s) }
  =                                     { \s -> TokSlash}
  \|                                    { \s -> TokPipe }
  \/                                    { \s -> TokSlash }
  \n                                    { \s -> TokEol}
  \%$alpha+                              { \s -> TokVar (drop 1 s)}

{
strip :: String -> String
strip s = take ((length s) - 2) (drop 1 s)

data Token = TokIdent String
           | TokStr String
           | TokEq
           | TokPipe
           | TokSlash
           | TokEol
           | TokVar String
             deriving (Eq,Show)
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I think that in the generated file the imports came first. I'll check when I have time

Comment: @user1528601 Tell me when you figure it out then. The code I gave you ran just fine when I tested it.